# How to remove a nested div in HTML via child selector

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, parent, removechild

how can I select and remove the div shown in the picture with a red frame:

[image]

I dont get any jQuery selection correctly, in my opinion I need to find div with title = Heatmap, then navigate two divs up and delete the whole div - is this possible ?? 
Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean *div with title = Heatmap*..? I don't see any `<div>` with `title` attribute... and what do you mean *"then navigate two divs up and delete the whole div"*..? Why not delete the whole `<div>` in the first place..?

Comment: Can you not add for example a specific class to your divs on the server side to differentiate them from each other?

Comment: `$('[title=Heatmap]').parent().parent().remove()` is literally what you said.... How could you not find it ;) Could be optimised though

Comment: why is it put on hold? I am asking how to remove the DIV in my HTML shown on the picture?

Comment: and also someone answered correctly, so how might it be unclear what I asked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the element is always in that position within your `.viz-controls-switchbar-switcher-container` element, you can use:

```
$('.viz-controls-switchbar-switcher-container').children(':nth-child(5)').remove();
```

Otherwise yes, you can just:

```
$('[title="Heatmap"]').closest('.viz-controls-switchbar-switcher').remove();
```

Or:

```
$('[title="Heatmap"]').parents('.viz-controls-switchbar-switcher').remove();
```

Or:

```
$('[title="Heatmap"]').parent().parent().remove();
```

Or, if your element always has a `style` attribute stating with `left: 73px;...` you can use:

```
$('.viz-controls-switchbar-switcher[style^="left: 73px"]').remove();
```

Comment: Should use children in case an other div has 5 childrens or more.

Comment: And closest instead of parents.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon true, but it doesn't look like it does. I've updated the answer to use that now anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I know, just in case, i've already upvoted, just trying the give the best advice ;)